# Resnick Exercise 6.12 - Standard Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

How to verify the following for standard Brownian motion? 
$$P( \bigcup_{0 \leq t \leq 1} |B(t)| < b) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^k P( (2k-1)b < B(1) < (2k+1)b) $$
My initial thoughts are that the LHS is the same as $P(\sup_{0\leq t \leq 1}|B(t)| < b)$ and I would use that $P(|B(t)| < b) = 2P(B(t) < b) -1$ in conjunction with the reflection principle, but I am not sure about how this links with the RHS?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Since $|B_0|<b$ holds trivially for any $b>0$, the probability on the left-hand side is just $1$ (whereas the sum on the right-hand side will depend on $b$). Perhaps you meant to write $\bigcap_{0 \leq t \leq 1}$ instead of $\bigcup_{0 \leq t \leq 1}$?

Comment: I just copied what was written in the textbook, which was a union. I think Resnick defines "standard" Brownian motion without the condition $B(0)=0$, so I am not sure that he considers the LHS being trivially equal to 1.